# Recompiling PV kernel: unable to get domain type for domid=4

Tags: kernel, xen

After a few attempts I have managed to get Xen up and running on my device, with an Ubuntu focal dom-0.

I set up a PV guest ubuntu-focal instance, and am able to use it as expected. I'd like to recompile the kernel of my PV guest.

I copied over the /boot/config file of the guest, built the focal kernel and installed it within the PV guest. At this point I get the following error when booting up the guest.

```
libxl: error: libxl_dom.c:38:libxl__domain_type: unable to get domain type for domid=4
xl: unable to exec console client: No such file or directory
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:117:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: console child [4481] exited with error status 1
```

1. For PV guests is there a separate kernel source tree I should be building from?
2. Would there be a way to boot the PV guest with the older kernel? I don't mind setting up the PV guest from scratch, but would like to avoid it if possible.
3. Where can I look for more detailed error logs on what is occuring?